# exposure of DAL in razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, razor, model, viewmodel

I use Entity Framework 6 , code first approach, together with asp.net mvc 5.

the razor views are all strongly typed, and most of them use viewmodels that contain DAL models. Some views use models directly from the DAL. I am wondering what kind of security risks this. Let me demonstrate:

```
public class SomeViewModel {
    public SomeModel SomeModel {get;set;}
    public int OtherProperty {get;set;} 
}
```

in razor view:

```
@model SomeViewModel
```

What I expose to the razor view is, amongst others, 2 potentially security-risky things: the db id of the SomeModel instance, and the entity's dynamic proxy id ( or whatever that is), which i guess is related to the lazy loading of the entities.

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SomeModel_2ED515217...etc
```

So my plan is to make sure that all razor views utilize viewmodels ONLY. Also, all view models should exclude the above 2 mentioned things, the db id and the dynamic proxy id.

So `SomeViewModel` would become something like this:

```
public class SomeViewModel {
    public int SomeModelId {get;set;}
    public string SomeModelPropA {get;set;}
    public string SomeModelPropB {get;set;}
    public int OtherProperty {get;set;} 
}
```

To sum up, is it a good idea to be very restrictive regarding what razor views use for model? 
I know razor views are server side compiled, but what if a razor developer by accident use some of the 'forbidden' view model properties?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as long as you do not expose this stuff outside of your server this is quite fine... But even if user will see the DB's Id of your record - the security risks arises only when he can do something with it. Until then - it's just a number. You better think on how to protect Edit / Delete operations instead :)

Since we are there - think about one thing - when you strip your view model of all identifiers - how are you going to map things back when trying to update user's changes? Of course, it's not an issue if ViewModel is going to be read-only.

But anyway - I would strongly suggest to remove whole model objects from ViewModel objects - leave only some identifiers. If you have security concerns - maybe just try hashing them before?

And keep in ViewModel only as few fields / properties as required. And strictly defined. Not only for security reasons, but also to lower memory /transfer data usage.

Comment: great thanks! the viewmodel will ofcourse include identifiers as necessary, will clarify the code example